# org.w3c.dom.Document xml parsing wrong

Tags: xml, dom, sax, xerces

I am using apache xerces DOMParser and org.w3c.dom.Document to parse an xml document.
While trying to find a element and set some text content there is no error thrown but the
setNodeValue(String) method is not setting any content to the node. the node is a text node.
When I debugged I saw the properties like nextSibling or firstChild are #text or \n. 
How to remove these whitespaces and #text ? and why setNodeValue() method is not working?

I have one more question:
How to getElementBytagName document elements with namespaces for example "tns:result" ?

Inthe below xml:

```
<document xmlns:tns="....">
<header>
 <tns:username/>
</header>
</document>
```

document.getElementsByTagName("tns:username").items(0).setNodeValue("hello");

but after doing this the result xml is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

When the node type is `ELEMENT_NODE` (as it is in your case) calling `setNodeValue(...)` has no effect (see the documentation for `Node#setNodeValue(String ...)`.  You must create a child text node instead.

As to the text node you are seeing, they are in the document. If you remove them you'd have all the tags on a single line.  When processing XML you must be prepared to ignore insignificant whitespace.  The parser can't do that for you as it doesn't know which whitespace is insignificant to *you*.

Comment: I removed the whitespaces but still I am getting the node type = 1 for the node tns:username. Any idea what is the reason ?

Comment: Node type 1 is `ELEMENT_NODE`, which is correct.  If you want to convert `<tns:username/>` to `<tns:username>myUserName</tns:username>` you have to add a child text node to contain the user name value.